# Create multiple visuals per generated item

Tags: wpf, xaml, itemscontrol

Here's the plan. I have an `ItemsControl` that will have a two columns `Grid` as its main panel:

```
<ItemsControl>
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="70" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="*" />
          <RowDefinition Height="*" />
          <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      </Grid>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```

For each item in the underlying VM, I need to generate a `Label` that will go into first column, and a `Rectangle` that will go into the second one. How can I achieve this?

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate DataType="local:TimeSlotVM">
    ???
  </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: You can use `Grid` with 2 columns as `ItemTemplate` and remove one column definition from the `ItemsPanelTemplate`. Or you cann't?

Comment: @bars222: Hmm... Maybe I can. But how do I ask items to choose there row?

Comment: Yes it's the problem.. Probably it's better to move whole grid into `ItemTemplate` and adjust it for a `TimeSlotVM` item.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to use Grid.Row attached property, then assign this attached property to the parent ContentPresenter by the GridHelper.

And the visual tree will be like that:

```
Grid
 -ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1"
  -Gird 
 -ContentPresenter Grid.Row="0"
  -Gird 
 -ContentPresenter Grid.Row="2"
  -Gird
 ...
```

GridHelper.cs

```
public class GridHelper
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty GridRowProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("GridRow", typeof(bool), typeof(GridHelper),
            new PropertyMetadata(false, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnGridRowPropertyChanged)));

    public static bool GetGridRow(DependencyObject d)
    {
        return (bool)d.GetValue(GridRowProperty);
    }

    public static void SetGridRow(DependencyObject d, bool value)
    {
        d.SetValue(GridRowProperty, value);
    }

    private static void OnGridRowPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Grid grid = d as Grid;
        bool gridRow = (bool)e.NewValue;

        if (gridRow)
        {
            // construct the required row definitions
            grid.LayoutUpdated += (s, e2) =>
            {
                // iterate over any new content presenters (i.e. instances of our DataTemplate)
                // that have been added to the grid
                var presenters = grid.Children.OfType<ContentPresenter>().ToList();
                foreach (var presenter in presenters)
                {
                    // the child of each DataTemplate
                    var itemGrid = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(presenter, 0) as Grid;
                    if (itemGrid != null)
                    {
                        Grid.SetRow(presenter, Grid.GetRow(itemGrid));
                        if (Grid.GetRow(itemGrid) > grid.RowDefinitions.Count - 1)
                        {
                            presenter.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ItemList}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid Name="outer" local:GridHelper.GridRow="True">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    ...
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            </Grid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Grid.Row="{Binding Row}">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="70" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding Field}" />
                <Rectangle Grid.Row="{Binding Row}" Grid.Column="1" Fill="Blue" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Why are you filling `ItemTemplate` with all those `Label`/`Rectangle` pairs? I thought we should only have one `Label`/`Rectangle` pair per item, no? (I added 3 rows in the question just to keep things simple. In actuality there are 24 rows in the main panel.

Comment: Also note that I can't use a `StackPanel` as the main panel. I need to ensure that the panel divides the control height equally among all rows; hence a Grid with `Height="*"`.

Comment: I miss understood your question. Please find the edit.

Comment: `UniformGrid` is seemingly not working for me. It generates only as many rows as there are items in the VM, whereas I need fixed 24 rows. But more importantly, I need each item to choose its row based on a VM property. I was using `Grid.Row` attached property for this purpose earlier. With your `UniformGrid`, there's no attached property to use.

Answer (score 0):

What about using a UniformGrid and a Collection of 24 Empty TimeSlotVM's and then insert your TimeSlotVM at the desired postion in the Collection like this :

in your VM :

```
TimeSlotCollection=new ObservableCollection<TimeSlotVM>(new TimeSlotVM[24]);
            TimeSlotCollection.Insert(10,new TimeSlotVM());
            TimeSlotCollection.Insert(5, new TimeSlotVM());
```

and in your View :

```
 <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TimeSlotVM}">
                <Grid >
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="70" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding BindingField}" />
                    <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Fill="Blue" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding TimeSlotCollection}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Rows="24"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>  
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to share your idea. My approach would be to keep the underlying collection unaffected and instead try to relate `Grid.Row` attached property to dictate the row position of a time slot object, instead of injecting 20-so empty objects in the collection.